# Printable version of Haskell standard library

Tags: haskell

Are there any offline documentation versions of the Haskell standard library? In other words, I am searching a book or downloadable tutorial about Haskell library?

Comment: Well, there's the question of what do you mean by the "Haskell standard library."  While if we read you very strictly we'd take you to mean the libraries required by the Haskell 2010 Report, there's two other candidates of interest: (a) the [libraries included in GHC](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/index.html), and (b) the [libraries included in the Haskell Platform](http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/frames.html).  You won't find printed versions of (b), I'm sure.

Answer (score 5):

You can try the actual [Haskell 2010 Report](http://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf); there's also the [Tour of the Haskell Prelude](http://cs.anu.edu.au/student/comp1100/Papers/Tour_of_Prelude.pdf) originally by Bernie Pope; this version has been edited and updated slightly by Clem Baker-Finch.

Comment: I like Tour of the Haskell Prelude. Thanks